# SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: -ERR Unknown command

Tags: php

I am trying to send an e-mail using this PHP code:

```
        require("PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
        require("PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");
        require("PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php");

        $from  = "admin@mydomain.com";
        $namefrom = "admin";
        $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();   // by SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;   // user and password
        $mail->Host       = "mail.gandi.net";
        $mail->Port       = 110;
        $mail->Username   = $from;
        $mail->Password   = "Password123";

        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
//        $mail->SMTPSecure = "";    // options: 'ssl', 'tls' , ''  
        $mail->setFrom($from,$namefrom);   // From (origin)
        $mail->addCC($from,$namefrom);      // There is also addBCC
        $mail->Subject  = "Some subject";
        $mail->AltBody  = "Altenrate";
        $mail->Body = "Heyheyhey";
        $mail->isHTML(false);   // Set HTML type
        $mail->addAddress("hello@hotmail.com", "hello@hotmail.com");
        if($mail->send())
        {
          echo "ok sent";
        }
        else
        {
             echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }

    }
```

Thing is when using this code, it takes ages to load and ends up showing this error to me:

```
2018-12-09 20:50:24 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mydomain.be
2018-12-09 20:53:24 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: -ERR Unknown command.-ERR Disconnected for inactivity.
2018-12-09 20:53:24 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Could someone explain me what the issue is and how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the Port 110 correct? Shouldn't it be 465 or 587

Comment: @ivion when using this e-mail adress with thunderbord and no security it automatically sets itself to 110

Comment: Port 110 is used for POP, which is a protocol to retrieve your own mail. You need to use the SMTP server port to send mail (usually 25 or 587)

Answer (score 1):

you have the wrong settings according to :https://docs.gandi.net/en/gandimail/standard_email_settings/index.html

it should be

```
Outgoing (SMTP) server name: mail.gandi.net
Port: 25, 465 (with SSL) or 587 (with STARTTLS)
TLS or SSL: yes
SMTP Authentication: yes, using the same settings as for the POP / IMAP account
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello traducerad,

```
$mail->isSMTP();   // by SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;   // user and password
$mail->Host       = "mail.gandi.net";
$mail->Port       = 110;
$mail->Username   = $from;
$mail->Password   = "Password123";
// $mail->SMTPSecure = "";
```

Port 110 is for incoming POP communication.
I think you want to send an email via SMTP.

> Outgoing (SMTP) server name: mail.gandi.net
>   Port: 25, 465 (with SSL) or 587 (with STARTTLS)
>   TLS or SSL: yes
>   SMTP Authentication: yes, using the same settings as for the POP / IMAP account

[FAQ from gandi.net](https://docs.gandi.net/en/gandimail/standard_email_settings/index.html)